# Redirected to same page after POST method django

Tags: python, html, django

I am creating this project in django. I am working on reporting films, where I go to a film-detail view, then hit the report button. A report_form shows up where I justify why I am reporting, and then I click report. Everything works fine, but there is one thing. After reporting I get sent back to a random(?) film-detail view, but I would like to go back to the view for the film I am reporting. But how???

**views.py**

```
class FilmReportView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Report
    fields = ['reason']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.reporter = self.request.user
        form.instance.reports_id = self.kwargs['pk']
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return "film/<int:pk>/report"
```

**report_form.html**

```
{% extends "board/base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% load materializecss %}
{% block content %}
<div class="valign-wrapper row login-box">
    <div class="col card hoverable s10 pull-s1 m6 pull-m3 l8 pull-l2">
        <form method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="card-content">
                <span class="card-title">Jusity why you want to report this film?</span>
                <div class="row">
                    {{ form|materializecss }}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-action right-align">
                <input type="reset" id="reset" class="btn-flat grey-text waves-effect">
                <input type="submit" class="btn green waves-effect waves-light" value="Report">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.films_view, name="board-home"),
    path("film/add", FilmAddView.as_view(), name="film-add"),
    path("film/<int:pk>/", FilmDetailView.as_view(), name="film-detail"),
    path("film/<int:pk>/report", FilmReportView.as_view(), name="film-report"),
]
```

**models.py**

```
class Report(models.Model):
    reason = models.TextField()
    reporter = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="Reporter")
    reports = models.ForeignKey(Film, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):  # pragma: no cover
        return f"{self.reports.title} reported by {self.reporter.username}"

    def get_absolute_url(self):  # pragma: no cover
        return reverse("film-detail", kwargs={"pk": self.pk})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix your FilmReportView `get_success_url()` to look like that:

```
def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse("film-detail", kwargs={"pk": self.object.reports.id})
```

That should take care of it

Comment: I did. Now I get a 404, and the query still increments by one. Do I have to flush or something to restart?? I only have 20 films in my data, and for each time I report now I get like requested url; film/43, film/44 etc...

Comment: Sorry for the typo above, I fixed the `kwargs` dict ))

Answer (score 0):

In your `views.py` or even in the template you can put `next` parameter with url you want:

```
form/action/url?next={{request.path}}
```

See more about next:
https://www.reddit.com/r/django/comments/32s9ag/how_do_i_set_the_next_context_variable_in_django/

Comment: So I can just at "form/action/url?next={{request.path}}" in my views.py? Do I need to have it inside its own def?